# Sql Inner Join Dont Have Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

First of all thanks a lot all replys and comments. I want to listed some fields from 4 tables. My question is if ODEMELER(Customer Payments) tables is dont have BORCLAR(Customers Debt) tables value. Namely;

MusteriID is = 1.

This Customer buy a item. I insert this process to BORCLAR table(BorcMusteriID=1) but ODEMELER table is null for this customer and OdemeMusteriID=!!! (null) because customer is not payment. And i want to list all of debts from all customers this code;

```
(SELECT SUM(BORCLAR.BorcTutari) FROM BORCLAR WHERE BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=
    ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)-
    (SELECT SUM(ODEMELER.OdemeTutar) FROM ODEMELER where BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=
    ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID))
    AS [Borç Toplamı] FROM BORCLAR)
```

but this code is reply me only have BorcMusteriID,OdemeMusteriID valid records then my a lot of customers buy items but dont payment now. I dont list this. I try this code but it is wrong;

```
    ((SELECT SUM(BORCLAR.BorcTutari) FROM BORCLAR WHERE
 BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)-
(SELECT SUM(ODEMELER.OdemeTutar) FROM ODEMELER where 
BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=
CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ODEMELER WHERE 
ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID=BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID)
        WHEN 0 THEN ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID  = ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID
       ELSE ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID=0 END)) AS [Borç Toplamı] FROM BORCLAR
```

Complete of my code;

```
  set dateformat dmy
    SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 BORCLAR.BorcTarih FROM BORCLAR WHERE BORCLAR.BorcTarih <= 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 104)

    and

    BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=MUSTERILER.MusteriID order by BORCLAR.BorcTarih desc)
     as [TARİH], 

    MUSTERILER.Unvan,MUSTERILER.Ad + ' ' + MUSTERILER.Soyad AS [Adı Soyadı],
    MUSTERILER.Mahalle + 
    ' ' + MUSTERILER.Cadde + ' '+MUSTERILER.Sokak + ' ' + MUSTERILER.ApartmanAdi+ 
    ' NO:' +
    MUSTERILER.Numara + ' KAT:' + MUSTERILER.Kat + ' DAİRE:'+
    MUSTERILER.Daire  AS [Adres],
    ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeAdi as [Araç/Şube Adı], 

    ((SELECT SUM(BORCLAR.BorcTutari) FROM BORCLAR WHERE BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=
    ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)-
    (SELECT SUM(ODEMELER.OdemeTutar) FROM ODEMELER where BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=
    ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID))
    AS [Borç Toplamı] FROM BORCLAR

    INNER JOIN ARACSUBETANIMLAR ON BORCLAR.BorcAracSube = ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeID
    INNER JOIN ODEMELER ON BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID = ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID
    INNER JOIN MUSTERILER ON BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID = MUSTERILER.MusteriID

    where 
    BORCLAR.BorcAracSube=ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeID
     and 
    ((SELECT SUM(BORCLAR.BorcTutari) FROM BORCLAR WHERE BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=
    ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)-
    (SELECT SUM(ODEMELER.OdemeTutar) FROM ODEMELER where BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=
    ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)>0)

    group by MUSTERILER.Unvan,MUSTERILER.Soyad,MUSTERILER.Ad,
    ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeAdi,
    ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID,BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID,MUSTERILER.
    Cadde,MUSTERILER.Daire,
    MUSTERILER.ApartmanAdi,MUSTERILER.Mahalle,MUSTERILER.Kat,
    MUSTERILER.Numara,MUSTERILER.Sokak,
    MUSTERILER.MusteriID
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you try, by replace your INNER JOIN by LEFT JOIN? And then, check the result with it.

Comment: I replace the LEFT JOIN but result is not change.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want all customer balances regardless whether they have paid anything or not.  You have purchases in one table (BORCLAR) and payments in the other table (ODEMELER).  I am not sure what language you are speaking, but I guess "MusteriID" is the customer ID.  You can use CTEs to get total purchases and payments by customer first and then join on that.  Something like this:

```
;WITH BorclarTotal AS (
    SELECT  BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID, SUM(BORCLAR.BorcTutari) AS BorcTutari
    FROM    BORCLAR
    GROUP BY BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID
), OdemelerTotal AS (
    SELECT  ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID, SUM(ODEMELER.OdemeTutar) AS OdemeTutar
    FROM    ODEMELER
    GROUP BY ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID
)
SELECT  bt.BorcMusteriID, bt.BorcTutari - ISNULL(ot.OdemeTutar, 0)
FROM    BorclarTotal bt
        LEFT JOIN OdemelerTotal ot ON bt.BorcMusteriID = ot.OdemeMusteriID
WHERE   bt.BorcTutari != ISNULL(ot.OdemeTutar, 0);
```

Comment: MusteriID=CustomerID, sorry this i forget it to write this. I need sum of (debt-payment). But my code runing this if customer dont make any payment (debt-??!?!?!). Your code is working for ID's then give me right debts ID's. Namely now; How am i integrated your code to my too long codes and how am i get the without payments total debts.

Comment: @EthemX The ones without any payments are included in the above query.  If you *only* want those with no payments, then those are the records where the LEFT JOIN has no match, so in the WHERE clause, use " WHERE ot.OdemeMusteriID IS NULL ".  In the final SELECT, add " bt.BorcTutari - ISNULL(ot.OdemeTutar, 0) " to see the totals (I edited my answer to include the total debits - credits). If you want an easy way to integrate into your code, just insert the above into a #temp table and then use it in subsequent queries.

Comment: i try integrate my code for this but having an error; Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'BORCLAR.BorcAracSube' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: my problem is now i have ARACSUBETANIMLAR(departments). Namely; A person buy product department1 and department2 and i hope to my sql code is show this departments and total (debits-credits). You look this image and maybe tell me an answer. http://t1307.hizliresim.com/1c/u/qtn2m.png

Comment: And i thinks this code is wrong;  ... `bt.BorcMusteriID, bt.BorcTutari - ISNULL(ot.OdemeTutar, 0) FROM BorclarTotal bt
        LEFT JOIN OdemelerTotal ot ON bt.BorcMusteriID = ot.OdemeMusteriID
        LEFT JOIN ARACSUBETANIMLAR ON bt.BorcAracSube = ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeID
        LEFT JOIN MUSTERILER ON bt.BorcMusteriID = MUSTERILER.MusteriID
    WHERE bt.BorcAracSube=ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeID
     and    bt.BorcTutari != ISNULL(ot.OdemeTutar, 0) 
     group by MUSTERILER.Unvan,`....

Comment: You should really go to SQLFiddle.com & set up your structure (with a small amount of sample data).  Then come back here and post the SQLFiddle link.  It sounds like you need to aggregate debits-credits on more than CustomerID, you also need to do it by department?  Looks from your code that you have the department associated with the purchase (debit), but do you also have it associated with the credit?  If not, how will you know which cust / dept combo to associate a payment with?  Is your expected output what you posted in the image?

Comment: A department (ARACSUBETANIMLAR) "ARAÇ -1-" sell a product from CustomerID=1(MusteriID). insert this process from debits(BORCLAR). But without payment. After this process i select to; this customer name ,adress,total debits, bought which department. Department table name is (ARACSUBETANIMLAR). I'm sorry. And enormous thanks @kev

Comment: @Ethem I looked at your SQL Fiddle. The logic for how credits are applied to debits is incomplete. The debit transactions have the Department, but the credits do not (the field is there in the table but you left it NULL in your sample data). So how do credits get applied to debits? In your example, customer 1 is debited 250 for dept 1 and 350 for dept 2.  Then cust 1 has credits of 150 and 250. What is the rule for how those credits are applied to the previous debits?  This is not a coding issue, it is a business rule that must be decided first.

Comment: No no, i want only saw which department give product. Total value of purchase i want saw it. My wrong code is this; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97b80/1 please look this. CustomerID(MusteriID)=3 person have 1300 debts. But i dont list it because ODEMELER table dont have "CustomerID(MusteriID)=3" because without payment yet. Then sum(debts-payments) dont work correctly beacause this customer not pay yet. Really sorry for waste your time.